# iOS automatic hover fix?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, hover

Is there a jQuery plugin or JavaScript script that automagically loops through each CSS hover (found in an external stylesheet) and binds it with a double touchdown event?

- Touchdown 1 - CSS :hover is triggered
- Touchdown 2 - Click (link following or form action)

If there isn't something like this yet, can it be made and how (guidelines)?

EDIT:

To be clear, I am not in search of a double tap. Touchdown 1 is a single tab just like Touchdown 2 is. There can be as less as 0 seconds between both or as much as 3 minutes, that's the user's choice.

No touch:

- :hover -> element becomes visible
- click -> following link or other action

Touch (iOS):

- touchdown 1 -> element becomes visible
- touchdown 2 -> following link or other action

Comment: That would break the consistency of the UI, particularly requiring a double-tap for navigation (double-tap is already overloaded, it can mean zoom in/out or bring up a context menu). There is no hover for iOS devices, there are only clicks and drags.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you have important information that appears on hover. Example: http://html5awesome.com/. Go over one of the screenshots and you will see two actions: love and visit. Don't get those on iOS. You go directly to another page.

Comment: But what? As stated, that's just how it works. The concept of over doesn't exist on a touch device. If you want to expose that same information somehow, you need to come up with an alternative means. As stated, a double-tap is already taken by the OS itself. The typical suggestion is to add a separate visual to access said info such a help icon (?)

Comment: Off course. But :hover does exist in the stylesheet. And the touchdown event does exist. By the way, my example doesn't show a double tap. It is a single tap that triggers action 1 and another single tap that triggers action 2. I've seen this many times while visiting websites on iPad and it is possible. I am just asking for some guidelines or something that can automate this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>iPad Experiment</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(navigator.platform == "iPad") {
                $("a").each(function() { // have to use an `each` here - either a jQuery `each` or a `for(...)` loop
                    var onClick; // this will be a function
                    var firstClick = function() {
                        onClick = secondClick;
                        return false;
                    };
                    var secondClick = function() {
                        onClick = firstClick;
                        return true;
                    };
                    onClick = firstClick;
                    $(this).click(function() {
                        return onClick();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:hover {
            color:white;
            background:#FF00FF;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.ca">Google</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

... or check out the [demo on my web site](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/stack-overflow/iOS-automatic-hover-fix.html). Note that it's set up to only work its magic on the iPad - detecting all versions of the iOS is another question in my books ;)

It works on the basis of the fact that...

> After you click a link on the iphone or ipad, it leaves a simulated mouse hover that triggers the a:hover css styling on that link. If the link has a javascript handler that keeps you on same page, the hover state will not change until you click on another link.

Citation: [Safari iphone/ipad “mouse hover” on new link after prior one is replaced with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120497/safari-iphone-ipad-mouse-hover-on-new-link-after-prior-one-is-replaced-with-jav)

Comment: Thanks! Gonna check that out.

Comment: Magically working! Is there a way to remove the hover state when you click anywhere else on the page (not only anchor elements)?

Comment: @DADU - Sorry, I don't know how to do that :( but I'll think about it.

Comment: For html click use:           var navigationActive = $("#mainNavigation > li");function htmlClick () {
        if ($(navigationActive).hasClass("hover")) {
            $(navigationActive).removeClass("hover");
            $(navigationActive).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        }
    } if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
            $("html").click(htmlClick); 
        }

Answer (score 6):

I've used this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

Before, to allow hover on certain elements. Obviously you'll need to tweak it for your own use, but it's a nice way to allow a touch and hold hover effect.

Comment: It looks like you need to add the .hover_effect classname to every :hover in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: In the site I was using, this is what I did, as I didn't want every hover to act in this way. You could add the event to every element, but that seems wasteful, and will preventDefault on too much. In the end I settled on this as it seemed a happy compromise.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a further optimized version that also handles *closing* the :hover

You'll have to encapsulate your site with a

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

for it to work. Just putting the closing event on the body did nothing

```
var bodyBound = false;
var container;

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))
{
    container = $("#container");

     // Provoke iOS :hover event
    $("a.someLink").on("mouseover", handleHoverClick);
}

function handleClose(event)
{
    container.off("click", handleClose);

    bodyBound = false;
}

function handleHoverClick(event)
{
    if (!bodyBound)
    {
        bodyBound = true;

        // Somehow, just calling this function—even if empty—closes the :hover
        container.on("click", handleClose);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created this update apon Richard JP Le Guens solution. It works GREAT, but my version fixes the issue recognized by DADU.

Also I fixed his workaround to detect iPads. My solution detects any other touch devices too (except IE10 on MS surface, I didn't remember the MS special treatment).

My fix is not a 100% perfect solution, but it resets the hover fix at least when hovering another link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TouchDevice Experiment</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(document.createEvent("TouchEvent")) { // using document.createEvent is more reliable than navigator (Modernizr uses this practice)
                $("a").each(function() { // have to use an `each` here - either a jQuery `each` or a `for(...)` loop
                    var onClick; // this will be a function
                    var firstClick = function() {
                        $("a").trigger("JWUnhover"); // triggering hoverfix reset if any link gets touched

                        onClick = secondClick;
                        return false;
                    };
                    secondClick = function() {
                        onClick = firstClick;
                        return true;
                    };
                    onClick = firstClick;
                    $(this).click(function() {
                        return onClick();
                    });
                    $(this).bind('JWUnhover', function(){ onClick = firstClick; });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:hover {
            color:white;
            background:#FF00FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.ca">Google</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no jQuery plugin that I know of to do such a thing.

You cannot trigger a css psuedo class such as ":hover". You can however loop through the anchor elements and add a css class ".hover" on touchstart and touchend events as follows:

```
    var pageLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; i++){
    pageLinks[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(){this.className = "hover";}, false);
    pageLinks[i].addEventListener('touchend', function(){this.className = "";}, false);
}
```

To add a double finger tap gesture recognizer, you can use a plugin such as:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multiswipe

Comment: Thanks. I am going to test this out.

Comment: Seems not to be what I am after. Nevertheless you gave some good input so that deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
// Ipad Navigation Hover Support
    $('#header .nav li a').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        if( $(this).attr("href") != "" ){
            window.location = $(this).attr("href");
        }

    });
```

Comment: This solved my issue with hover breaking parent <div> had a child <a href> and on Ipad the href was never being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optimized version of the jQuery code provided by Richard JP Le Guen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').each(function() {

        var clicked = false;

        $(this).bind('click', function() {

            if(!clicked) return !(clicked = true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: does this also close the hover if you touch somewhere else?

Comment: Probably not. You may try it though.

Comment: so this affects every single `<a>` on the page.  Is there something I can add to the jQuery to only have it affect `<a>`'s that contain a certain `class or id`?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can. Read up on [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors). E.g. you could use `$('a.classname').each` ...

Comment: Check this out minimized even farther here, and it works like a charm! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818353/how-to-apply-this-jquery-function-to-a-certain-class-only

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simpler way to fix the issue with iOS and hover states, using CSS. For the link you have an issue with set the `cursor` property to `pointer` and the hover state will be ignored on iOS. For all links to function as expected, see below:

```
a
{cursor: pointer;}
```