# How to apply this jQuery function to a certain class only

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(this).bind('click', function() {
        if(!clicked) return !(clicked = true);
    });
});
```

Hi all.  I'm trying to figure out how to apply this function to only `<a>` elements that also contain a class called `touch`.  In other words:

function **is** applied to this:

```
<a href="#" class="touch">
```

function **is not** applied to this:

```
<a href="#">
```

Sorry, I'm a jQuery newb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (combined with your current [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)):

```
$('a.touch').each(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    $(this).bind('click', function() {
        if(!clicked) return !(clicked = true);
    });
});
```

It's worth having a read through the jQuery API (in particular the [selectors section](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). It will save you a lot of time later on!

It's also worth remembering that the majority of jQuery selectors are the same as the CSS selectors. If you know anything about CSS, you can apply that knowledge to jQuery too.

---

On a separate note, since most jQuery methods apply to every element in the matched set, you can probably get rid of your `each` loop. If I've understood correctly, you are trying to prevent every `a.touch` element from following the link the first time it is clicked. If that's right, then you can just do this:

```
$('a.touch').one("click", function() {
    return false; 
});
```

​

Comment: @Shackrock - Yeah, that easy! I've updated my answer with a potential alternative to your code too (if I've understood what you're trying to do that is).

Comment: you're a genius on all accounts!  Simplified code works just the same, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses [CSS selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Change your selector to `$('a.touch')` for anchor tags with the `touch` class or just `$('.touch')` for any element that has the `touch` class.