# Issue with ios hover event

Tags: ios, css

I am currently having issues making iPad work with a :hover event. To clear up what i mean i have uploaded part of the website at http://playing.everythingcreative.co.uk and I have 3 images, that when hovered over a div disappears to show text underneath but this does not work on the iPad at all. I tried:

```
ontouchstart="touchStart(event);"
```

But i don't know enough on how it works to use it right.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You're trying to use hover events on a touch screen?

Comment: yeah basically...what i want is for the :hover event to act as a fadeout/fadein event when on ios

Comment: I guessed that otherwise i wouldn't be asking the question lol. I have found this which is specific for iPad but now my next issue will be to make it work for all touch screen devices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507964/ios-automatic-hover-fix

Comment: How exactly is **hover** supposed to work on an ipad without a mouse?

Comment: @Bot what I want it to do is work as a click when on a touch screen

Comment: If you've ever used a website that has hover event, you will note that the first touch activates the hover, and the 2nd touch clicks. I assume the OP wants this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out anyway using the example on [iOS automatic hover fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507964/ios-automatic-hover-fix) and changing:

```
if(navigator.platform == "iPad") {
```

to:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
```

The final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
            $("div").each(function() { // have to use an `each` here - either a jQuery `each` or a `for(...)` loop
                var onClick; // this will be a function
                var firstClick = function() {
                    onClick = secondClick;
                    return false;
                };
                var secondClick = function() {
                    onClick = firstClick;
                    return true;
                };
                onClick = firstClick;
                $(this).click(function() {
                    return onClick();
                });
            });
        }
    });
```