# hover stats of hyperlinks don't disappear by tapping other places in iOS

Tags: ios, css, hover

Please see the example page (http://goo.gl/d8n5W).

Because of how iOS handles the **CSS** `:hover` effect, users get the hover effect when they first time tapping on a **hyperlink**. And after they tap it again, the `onclick` event being triggered.

But if users decide not to go with the hyperlink after they first time tapping on it (that makes the hover effect appear), they can't make the hover effect disappear by tapping other places on the webpage.

The same issue happens on a hyperlink which opens its destination in a new window. By tapping on it, a new window is opened. And then you go back to the original window, you find the hyperlink's hover stat is on and won't disappear even if you tap other places.

Is there a way to make the hover effect disappear when users tap other places on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below stack overflow link might be helpful

[How do I simulate a hover with a touch in touch enabled browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851663/how-do-i-simulate-a-hover-with-a-touch-in-touch-enabled-browsers)

also useful resource

http://designshack.net/articles/css/are-hover-events-extinct/

also you might be looking for ios double tap issue

[iOS automatic hover fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507964/ios-automatic-hover-fix)

Hope this helps